# Prove by induction that there are infinitely many rational numbers between two distinct rational numbers.

Tags: induction

I need to prove by induction that if $x, y \in\mathbb{Q}$ with $x < y$, then there is an infinite increasing sequence $\{z_n\}_n$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $x < z_1 < z_2 < \dots < z_n < \dots < y$.

I have tried to use $a_n = x + \frac{y-x}{2^n}$ but am not being able to proceed.

Comment: Where is the induction ?

Comment: Let $b_n= y-2^{-n}(y-x)$.

Answer (score 3):

**Base case**: there is a rational number between the rationals $x$ and $y$. Indeed, $x<z=\frac{x+y}2<y$ and $z$ is a rational.

**Induction**: if there are $n>0$ rationals between $x$ and $y$, then there are $n+1$ rationals between $x$ and $y$. Indeed,

$$x<z_1<z_2\cdots z_n< y\implies x<\frac{x+z_1}2<z_1<z_2\cdots z_n<y.$$

---

A non-inductive proof can be "for all $n$, the numbers $\left(1-\frac in\right)x+\frac iny$ with $0<i<n$ are rational, distinct, in $(x,y)$ and increasing".

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track! However, if you need an increasing sequence take 
$$z_n = y - \frac{y-x}{2^n}.$$
(note that your sequence stays between $x$ and $y$ but it is decreasing).

Now try to verify that this sequence satisfies the required conditions.

Basic step. Verify $x<z_1<y$.

Inductive step. Verify that for $n\geq 1$, $z_n<z_{n+1}<y$.

Comment: I am stuck in trying to figure out the steps for going about such an induction problem. how do I prove that it is greater than y−(y−x)/2^(n+1)

Comment: @Ishan Bahl  $z_n<z_{n+1}$, because $(y−x)/2^{n+1} <(y−x)/2^n$

Comment: OP's $a_n = x + \frac{y-x}{2^n}$ also works, except it's a decreasing sequence instead.

Comment: Yes you are right, but in that case $x<z_n<\dots <z_2<z_1<y$. OP wants an increasing sequence.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a strictly monotonic increasing sequence of rational numbers, then you can also take the $z_{n}=y-\frac {y+z_{n-1}}{2}=\frac {y-z_{n-1}}{2}$ where you can define $z_0=x$.

The basis step and the induction step all hold since *sum, difference and division of two non-zero rational numbers **always** yield a rational number*.